# Found 0 JPA repository interfaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository

[image]

I have created a spring boot application and when tried to run it, it threw "Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces." All my packages are subpackage of the same package. I don't know why is it happening. Do help.

`

```
package com.newproject.repo;

import com.newproject.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

}
```

`

`

```
package com.newproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.newproject")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.newproject.controller.UserController", "com.newproject.service.UserService", "com.newproject.service.UserServiceImpl"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.newproject.repo.UserRepo")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.newproject.entities.User", "com.newproject.dto.UserDTO"})
public class NewprojectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(NewprojectApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

`

Comment: Have you tried `scanBasePackages = "com.newproject.repo"`  ?

Comment: Please do read: [Why not post images of errors, logs and code in a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please remove all annotations except @SpringBootApplication in your main class and try again

Comment: It looks normal as you missed the repo package in the `@ComponentScan` annotation. I personally don't use it to be able to define any components annotation (@Service, @Controller, @Repository, @Component etc...) in any package from the spring-boot app.

Comment: @PierreDemeestere Yes, I already have tried that.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal I started with that only, it threw error too.

Comment: @рüффп I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @BhaveshJha - can you please share your project code in github for debugging?

Comment: Try also `@EnableJpaRepositories` without options. You gave a Class FQDN and I think you only need to provide a package.

Comment: @рüффп if i do that, i get this error:  "Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in com.newproject.repo.UserRepo defined in EnableJpaRepositories declared on NewprojectApplication: Not a managed type: class com.newproject.entities.User"

Comment: @RohitAgarwal sure, i'll do that.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal https://github.com/bhaveshjh/newproject please find this.

Comment: @рüффп please check the code.

Comment: @BhaveshJha - Thanks for sharing the code, please read my answer for fix.

Comment: @BhaveshJha - did you check my answer? Is it is helpful?

Answer (score 2):

I have analysed the code and found couple of issues/improvements and finally issue is fixed. Here are the details.

1. This dependency is present in **pom.xml** but not required because `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is already present. So please remove this dependency. After removing this dependency you need to change **import statements** in entity classes from `javax.persistence.*` to `jakarta.persistence.*` because you are using Spring Boot 3.x and it Support Jakarta EE 10 with an EE 9 baseline.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. In Main class (`NewprojectApplication.java`) only one annotation (`@SpringBootApplication`) is enough. Please remove other annotations.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.newproject.repo.UserRepo", "com.newproject.controller.UserController", "com.newproject.service.UserService", "com.newproject.service.UserServiceImpl"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.newproject.repo.UserRepo")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.newproject.entities.User", "com.newproject.dto.UserDTO"})
```

3. You created entity with name `User` and there is no `@Table` annotation present in entity class so Spring framework trying to create `User` table in PostgreSQL database, that is not allowed because `User`is reserved word so please use some other table name using `@Table` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "MyUser")
public class User {}
```

4. In Main class (`NewprojectApplication.java`), you are extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` but not using any methods from parent class so better remove this.
5. In `application.properties` file this property is present

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Please change this property with value `update` otherwise on every restart new table will be created

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```